# Closed subset of metric space $M$

Tags: real-analysis

How would I prove that any finite subset of a metric space $M$ is closed? I would assume it would start with a sequence converging to a limit point,  but from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be a finite subset of metric space $M$.
For $a\in M\setminus S$, we have that $r:=\min\{\,d(a,s)\mid s\in S\,\}$ is positive. Hence the $d$-ball around $a$ is disjoint from $S$. We conclude that $M\setminus S$ is open, hence $S$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $S \subset M$ be a finite set. Show that $S$ has no limit points.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M=\{m_1,m_2,\cdots,m_{n}\}$ and $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots\}$ be a converging sequence in $M$. Let:

$$\epsilon=\min_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} d(m_i,m_j)$$

Now $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots\}$ converges, so it's Cauchy sequence, so:

$$\exists N \; \forall i,j \geq N \; d(a_i,a_j)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

So for all $i,j \geq $ you must have $a_i=a_j$ (if not $d(a_i,a_j) \geq \epsilon$).

Finally there exists $m_k$, that for $i>N$ we have $m_k=a_i$, so sequence $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots\}$ converges to $m_i \in M$.